# When I use auto layout & xib to make a uitableviewcell , why should I set the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to YES?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

In my opinion , if

`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES`

The layout system will generate some implicit constraints based on the current xib file size (like width and height),which are not suitable for the dynamic height cells (e.g there are multiple lines label in cell).

But in my project , if i set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO` in `awakeFromXib`, there will be a lot of layout problems, and if I set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints as default (yes). everything works fine. Both the widths will changed to tableview's width ,and the height will adjust based on multiple lines label. Was my understanding about translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the apple developer file, i got a rule ,maybe its use full for us

For views that are aware of Auto Layout, in most circumstances you want translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to be NO. The reason is that the constraints generated by translating the autoresizing mask are already sufficient to completely specify the frame of a view given its superview’s frame, which is generally too much. For example, this translation would prevent a button from automatically assuming its optimal width when its title is changed.

The principal circumstance in which you should not call setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: is when you are not the person who specifies a view’s relation to its container. For example, an NSTableRowView instance is placed by NSTableView. It might do this by allowing the autoresizing mask to be translated into constraints, or it might not. This is a private implementation detail. Other views on which you should not call setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: include an NSTableCellView object, a subview of NSSplitView, a view of NSTabViewItem, or the content view of an NSPopover, NSWindow, or NSBox object. For those familiar with classic Cocoa layout: If you would not call setAutoresizingMask: on a view in classic style, you should not call setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: under Auto Layout.

Answer (score 0):

Let iOs [do its internal stuff](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AdoptingAutoLayout/AdoptingAutoLayout.html) and try to limit the changes to your own views only, that is subviews of the `contentView`.

Comment: In fact , I have met a problem couple days ago when I use a custom view as tableHeaderView. I found that if I didn't set the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO ,then the custom view's height will always be the xib file's height . only if I set it to NO,the custom view's height will be adjust dynamiclly. so i was wondering why I have to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO in custom view and set it to YES in tableview cells?

Comment: The answer is at the linked article: "The principal circumstance in which you should not call setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: is when you are not the person who specifies a view’s relation to its container. For example, an NSTableRowView instance is placed by NSTableView. It might do this by allowing the autoresizing mask to be translated into constraints, or it might not. This is a private implementation detail." Whatever "solution" works for you at the current versions might stop working at any moment and you'll have nobody to blame.

Comment: but in some books like << programming IOS 7>> says like this ,and In my previous problem , you can't fix it until you manual set this flag to NO ---quote from book: "That’s a sensible rule, but it means that if you intend to apply any explicit constraints of your own to such a view, you’ll probably want to remember to turn off this automatic behavior by setting the view’s translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints prop‐ erty to NO. If you don’t, you’re going to end up with both implicit constraints and explicit constraints affecting this view, and it’s unlikely that you would want that"

Comment: so i want to dig more about the whole system ,and to know who the auto layout adjust all the tableView's components 's size and position:)

Comment: I believe that the correct way to use auto layout in this case is to try to do something with different priorities for your own constraints and more importantly it is necessary to research the system-generated constraints to understand what you are dealing with. Unfortunately I can't advice anything in particular as a guaranteed solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have autolayout constraints set properly in XIB/Storyboard then system itself will handle the layout sizing for you. That is the reason you set that boolean. If you are not setting constraints and not setting the bool then you are responsible for views sizing and positions which you have to handle in code. With new form factors introduced its best to use proper layouts and let autolayout system handle the frames for you.

Comment: In fact , I have met a problem couple days ago when I use a custom view as tableHeaderView. I found that if I didn't set the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO ,then the custom view's height will always be the xib file's height . only if I set it to NO,the custom view's height will be adjust dynamiclly. so i was wondering why I have to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO in custom view and set it to YES in tableview cells?